# SED replace indexed field

Tags: csv, sed, field

Is it possible to replace a field in the delimited string addressing it by its position?

```
aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd;sdfsfsdfsf;2324234234;dfdffdf;
```

Replace field 5 with something.

```
Here is my solution:

To replace a field NN+1 with BLAH in a semicolon delimited string:

    sed 's/\(\([^;]\+;\)\{NN\}\)[^;]\+;\(.*\)/\1BLAH;\3/'

for the PCRE variant:

    sed -r s/(([^;]*;){NN})[^;]*;(.*)/\1BLAH;\3/g

Thanks!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve this problem in your post in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: Post updated as I've found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

To replace a field NN+1 with BLAH in a semicolon delimited string:

```
sed 's/\(\([^;]\+;\)\{NN\}\)[^;]\+;\(.*\)/\1BLAH;\3/'
```

for the PCRE variant:

```
sed -r s/(([^;]*;){NN})[^;]*;(.*)/\1BLAH;\3/g
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sed.. but..

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$5="something"; print $0}' input.txt`

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} $5="something"' input.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus ... assuming `"something"` isn't in reality e.g. an empty string or a numeric zero.

Comment: @tripleee: yes, these assumptions are important.

Comment: @Cyrus don't use actions as conditions unless you NEED the result of the action to be treated as a condition as doing so saves you a couple of characters but then it always makes your code less clear and often less robust too.

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$5="something"} 1' input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^;]*/something/5' file
```